# Run custom script every time network is restarted

Tags: networking, fedora, systemd

When I restart my networking on Fedora24 with `systemctl restart network`, I would like a script to run automatically. The purpose of this script is to reattach some interfaces to some bridges. What is the best way to do this?

I tried `/sbin/ifup-local` as referenced from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-post`, but this only ever executes `/sbin/ifup-local` for the loopback interface. My bridges are brought up later, so this is no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your `ifcfg-eth0` (or whatever it is) has `NM_CONTROLLED=no` configuration.

This way it will not exclude all `ifup-*` scripts.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Why does NM prevent the scripts from running? Does NM have its own collection of scripts for managing interfaces? How can I influence/hook into NM's scripts (if applicable)?

Comment: from my understanding `NM_CONTROLLED=no` is the old way of managing networking. I'm surprised that in fedora it's default to no :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure it defaults to yes. I had to explicitly add the `=no` line for the ifup-local script to run. Thus was my question in the comment: if I leave the default behavior (NM_CONTROLLED=yes), is there a way I can hook into NM to do some post-up tasks? Is there a "right way" to hook custom processing into NM?